# Do capital letters make you seem serious?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

Lately, I've been seeing a trend of using lower-case letters over capital letters.

**Outlook**

Hello, *matthew*

**Smart Water**

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

In the above picture, there are many examples of simple sentence structure being ignored and lower case letters being used in place of upper-case structure.

**that's, but, it's.**

---

Is this now a thing? **Should my company follow the same strategy to appear more fun and creative?** I'm running a company where you can win sweepstakes. I want the environment to be fun and stimulate them to enter the contests.

Comment: personally, I think it's a cultural thing driven by younger demographics not using capitals in the informal communications on the devices they use the most: cell phones and computer. So in my (untested and unproven) theory, it's just a lame attempt to look "trendy". About your particular photo, I doubt it may pass many tests, but well, as long as it is "hip" who cares :)

Comment: I don't mind caps in tables but 'per' should not have been capitalized. It all seems pretty random.

Comment: y use words @ all when u can has much success with othr gr8 txt? It's sad that our society is catering to bad grammar and shit spelling. Gotta love Uhhmerica.

Comment: I think the "Per" is capitalized per the [FDA guidelines](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/LabelingNutrition/ucm274593.htm) for nutritional labels (although I can't find a specific regulation). I can't find a sample on the FDA site that does not capitalize "Per".

Comment: @EJP I like how you're thinking outside the box. Just so you know, the focus was meant to be on the text above Ingredients. For example: "water. *that's*", "electrolytes. *it's*"

Comment: It seems likely that your Outlook example is just because that's how you typed you (or HR, or an HR intern, or... ) typed your name in.

Comment: Well I would call that thinking *inside* the box ;-)

Comment: @Amadeus9 No, I can't stand writing my name as lowercase. I wrote my name as: Matthew. I gave Outlook as an example because your suppose to capitalize pronouns.

Comment: People actually read the blurb on bottles of water? This might be a US thing, I can't say I've noticed this in Britain (not that I buy much bottled water).

Comment: I actually didn't miss the capitals at the beginning of the sentences that much. I only began to groan when I got to the "new york" bit.

Comment: "You're" (you are) supposed to capitalize *proper*  nouns.  Pronouns like "he" are normal lower case.

Comment: I don't have evidence other than subjective experience, so just a comment: caps help me parse a sentence.  Say, I start reading a sentence and I know where it's going after about four words.  Then I often skip to the end.  The capital letter starting the next sentence helps me find it.  In my native German, it even helps me anticipate sentence structure before actually reading.

Comment: I hope so, as my current project's GUI uses them extensively, and it's a serious program. :P But that's mainly for consistency and readability, since ALL CAPS is visually a lot clearer/more unambiguous than _all lowercase and abandon all hope ye who use proper nouns or acronyms_. (Similarities to the Metro UI are wholly unintentional, and I certainly don't use a blinding white theme.)

Comment: @underscore_d Eugh, all caps is even worse, because then it feels like you're being yelled at.

Comment: @Pyritie In conversation, sure. In a UI with lots of (albeit sparsely layed out) labels, I don't make that connection, and caps are clearer and less squint-y. But hey, maybe I'll lowercase them eventually. For now, it works for me (and as it's currently only for my use, that's all that matters!)

Comment: @JDługosz Sorry for the grammar mistake. This makes this question even more ironic...

Comment: Remember MS Visual Studio. Everyone hated the all-cap menus and they backed off that and went back to titlecase innthe 2015 version.

Comment: Off topic, but I joined here just to ask this: Why on earth would **anyone** come up with such a dumb idea not only to spend energy (=CO2) on bottles, bottling the water and driving it around, but also evaporating it first? Even with electrolytes "added" (and where do they come from, what's left of the distillation?) I'd still won't drink it even if I got paid for it. There's a reason noone have been able to make seawater where animals survive, it's just more to it than "electrolytes". For something as important to your health as water and if you really need bottled water, stick to normal ones

Comment: Absolutely hilarious: "Total Fat 0g, Total Carbohydrate 0g, Protein 0g".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.typographicwebdesign.com/choosing-using-fonts/aesthetics-emotions/) lowercase are friendly :

> Words set in all lowercase letters are informal and tend to feel
>   friendly. Variations in form, rounded shapes, and no initial capital
>   letter give lowercase words a common, conversational feeling.

and uppercase are demanding :

> Words set in all caps feel important, powerful, reliable, and
>   enduring. The letters are big and demanding.

Additionally, according to this [article](http://practicaltypography.com/all-caps.html) lower case are much easier to read :

> At body text sizes, cap­i­tal let­ters—or sim­ply caps—are harder to
>   read than nor­mal low­er­case text. Why? We read more low­er­case
>   text, so as a mat­ter of habit, low­er­case is more fa­mil­iar and
>   thus more leg­i­ble. Fur­ther­more, cog­ni­tive re­search has
>   sug­gested that the shapes of low­er­case let­ters—some tall (dhkl),
>   some short (aens), some de­scend­ing (gypq)—cre­ate a var­ied vi­sual
>   con­tour that helps our brain rec­og­nize words. Cap­i­tal­iza­tion
>   ho­mog­e­nizes these shapes, leav­ing a rec­tan­gu­lar contour.

EDIT :

Just adding some extra reference from this [article](http://boxesandarrows.com/emotional-design-with-a-c-t-part-1/) :

> Friendly or Unfriendly?
>
> Friendly visual features could be described as positive, while
>   unfriendly visual features could be described as negative.
>   Friendliness is not only determined by what is said, but also by how
>   it is said (i.e. the tone of the conversation). Our tendency to assign
>   and characterize personality based on conversation is easily
>   recognizable in the example below. This example uses contrast, visual
>   weight, , color value, size and typography to alter the meaning that
>   is conveyed by the words. The content conveys the message, but the
>   look and feel change how that message is interpreted, altering the
>   meaning.
>
> Which of the statements below would you rather hold a conversation
>   with? Which one do you feel more compelled to approach or avoid? Which
>   one naturally grabs more of your attention? When it comes to
>   conversation, someone has to lead, and opposites attract.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the cited articles are enough to provide authority, but nice answer nevertheless!

Comment: Thank you for doing research. I'm tried of answers that just post opinions on UX issues. The articles may not be *the* absolute authority, but it's something. @Andrew didn't site any research.

Comment: @CodePlay , added an extra reference

Comment: The point of the article talking about uppercase being harder to read is to discourage writing in *all uppercase*. (The title of the document is "All caps"!) I would strongly contend that *all lowercase* text is harder to read than normal sentence-capitalized text because it makes it harder to scan for the start of sentences and for proper nouns.

Comment: Words set in ALL CAPS actually feels like Nigerian spam.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I don't have enough evidence to support this conclusively, but I think that the *need* to find sentences and specific words may be driven by what you're already used to.  Similar to some indigenous tribes that literally cannot count, even as adults, because all they've ever needed was "one, two, many".  Perhaps an extreme example, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: @jamesdlin: That said however, I do appreciate being able to pick apart what's being said and so I ultimately agree with you.  Just playing devil's advocate for a bit.

Comment: This EDIT of your was very unfriendly and demanding... :D

Comment: @AaronD I don't think that's the case, really. It's just about organization - if you understand the organization, it helps you fulfill your goals. That's why we use letters, words, sentences and paragraphs in the first place. That's why phonebooks are alphabetized. That doesn't mean there aren't cultures who don't have some "language feature", but it also doesn't mean that they do well without - go ask a Chinese person how well their phonebooks work and you'll see my point :)

Comment: @Mruf: Who are you referring to?  I hope it wasn't me, because it wasn't my intent, but it's hard to tell without the "@name" part.  EDIT: Okay, I looked at the edit history for the question, and I see what you mean now.  Nevermind.  :)

Comment: Very good comments by all, thank you. Just to make clear, I am generally not in favor of all lowercase that violates grammar rules. I was just trying to explain the benefits of this style and generally the impact of typography on readers psychology. Maybe in certain context this style is justifiable. I believe that sentence case style enhances the sentence structure which is a very importand language feature.

Answer (score 25):

Titling is generally done with one of the following cases:

- ALL CAPS
- Title Case
- Sentence case

Some people use a fourth

- no caps

The biggest disadvantage of using anything other than sentence case is that you may confuse meaning as it differs from the expected orthographic standard - you should never use anything other than sentence case for long pieces of text.

Other than that, caps are generally more aggressive than lower case.

I wouldn't use lower case for proper nouns as it seems a little disrespectful.

I think it's the German orthography that capitalises every noun.

In my own work I tend to use title case for titles and sentence case for everything else just because it makes everything clear, doesn't 'shout' too much and leaves an accessible, readable text.

Comment: Yes, German nouns are always capitalized, even when common and not at the beginning of a sentence.  If you read older documents in English, such as the US Declaration of Independence and Constitution, you'll see a lot of nouns capitalized that would not be in 21st-century English.

I have considered the no-caps thing an annoying affectation since I read my first "e. e. cummings" poem.

Comment: @MontyHarder note that "e. e. cummings" is a special case, in that it's specifically the preferred capitalization of a proper noun, similar to "iPhone", "eHarmony", or "xkcd".

Comment: Title Case Is Terrible For Sentences, I Can't Stop Myself From Pausing At Each Word (Like [Kirk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_T._Kirk), But Worse).  ;)

Comment: @Izkata: The comma splice doesn't help much either!

Comment: It's funny what you had mentioned, "I think it's the German orthography that capitalises every noun".  I work for thyssenkrupp, a german company, and we recently changed our name from ThyssenKrupp to just thyssenkrupp.  The reason for the change was we didn't want to sound like a demanding company - but a friendly one.  How political are we getting nowadays?

Comment: @Izkata: title case is [Terrible](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39790) [For](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8489) [SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27434) [Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26970) [Titles](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15578) as [Well](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9433).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, lower case is more informal and fun on a general basis but this is not only about lower Vs upper-case, **it's about breaking conventions**.

Unless your **brand strategy** sets you in the path of going against orthographic rules, just don't. Go deep into what it really means for your brand, run some quick test. Besides being not serious, you might find more meanings for this approach like: you don't care about conventions, formalities, rules or what people think at all.

Now, this not either good or bad, the important thing here is that **you have drawn a strategy for your brand and that this approach falls along with its values and objetives.** If it does, go ahead break the rules but don't go shy on it or it will look like a mistake rather than a statement.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that is a 'thing' probably was a 'thing' before and for some reason has been resurrected.

In essence capitalization appears to help emphasize certain things because by default in the English language most characters are written in lower case. In languages that don't use the 'alphabet' capitalization has no meaning whatsoever (just think about Chinese, Arabic, Japanese, etc). In the contemporary lingo of mobile phone communication the lines are a little bit blurred.

You asked:

> Should my company follow the same strategy to appear more fun and
>   creative? I'm running a company where you can win sweepstakes. I want
>   the environment to be fun and stimulate them to enter the contests.

But I think the answer is that capitalization might not have as much impact as you think it would, although it is something that you should take into account when dealing with the visual design aspects of any products/services that you are trying to design/develop. I would argue that the branding will have the biggest impact on making the company appear fun and creative, and whatever the branding guidelines dictate then you should follow that in your design to keep the consistency.

In terms of pure UX design, I would argue that both the visual design and interaction design go hand in hand to create the fun and creative (I would have thought excitement is a bigger element in sweepstakes), and certainly typography and the writing/content style relating to the voice and tone of your copy adds a lot of impact to this, but simply capitalizing where you think it might be effective... I don't know about that really.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a fan of using lower-case letters when there would normally be upper-case letters, like pronouns and the starts of sentences. Maybe I'm being cynical, but when a company makes the *calculated* decision to misuse lower-case text, it seems contrived. Whenever a person does it, I assume that person is pretentious.

Comment: Do you have any other reference than your own thoughts on this answer?

Comment: "Whenever a person does it, I assume that person is pretentious." Really? I just feel that the person hasn't judged capitalisation to be required or worth the slight effort in the given context (e.g. talking informally on the internet). I frequently make that judgment myself. Why exactly is this indicative of pretentiousness? In fact... I'd say it's only when a **brand** does it, then it's pretentious, since they're probably trying to appeal to a certain demographic in a 'cool tumblr grandad' fashion.

Comment: @underscore_d To be clear, I'm talking about people who don't spell their names in sentence case. It's an effort to appear humble, but there's the self-assumption that they're too important in the first place

Comment: @BennySkogberg No, but this site is too enamored with formal research anyway; there's not enough value given to the opinions of individuals. Tracking eye movements and measuring milliseconds is great, but the most important thing about UX is, all that user cares about is how an experience makes him or her *feel.* Like, "UX StackExchange isn't really that great and that's why I don't visit often."

Comment: @TimHuynh As most devs presumably aspire to such success where it'd be extremely impractical to get individual feedback from each user - or don't yet have a product for feedback precisely because they've not yet chosen a UX design - they then kinda have to rely on averaging studies that hopefully represent a typical, existing user. (Promoting inertia and tyranny of the majority, maybe, but hey!) It also seems impractical that every such user would weigh in with their own opinion in an answer on this or any other SE site. Hence the tendency to avoid opinion-based questions or answers, I presume